# What are the .LRV files on the gopro sdcard?

Tags: sdcard, gopro

I delete the .THM and .LRV files along with the MISC folder but what are they actually good for? THM is for thumbnails on the LCD so that is clear, and the rest?

Comment: What does this have to do with photography?

Comment: The question is photography related because the GoPro is a still camera, too. The answer should belong to AVP-SE but the question couldn't know that.

Comment: It is about photography, video photography. GPro, D4s and D610 owner. Thanks for the photography answers, much appreciated by a GP newbie.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

LRV is a Low Resolution Video on the GoPro. You can use it on your not-too-powerful computer, edit, and then for the final render use the original, high resolution video. You can view it by renaming to .mp4

Comment: Nice to know that GoPro can create proxy videos on-the-fly.

Answer (score 4):

It's for the GoPro apps (iOS and Android devices). The apps will not work without these files because the apps use them to show you the live feed without major lag.

Answer (score 4):

In an effort to make this question more about photography…

Protip: Change the extension of the GoPro `.THM` files to `.jpg` you'll have viewable JPG image files.